# Load more data ajax PHP onscroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on loading around 1000 products on a page and thought of following approach of `OnScroll` loading.

Below is the approach i am following:

```
<ul id="productContainer">
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var track_load = 0; //total loaded record group(s)
   var loading  = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
   var total_groups = 5;
   $('#productContainer').load("loadmore", 
    {'group_no':track_load}, function() {track_load++;});
   $(window).scroll(function() {
     if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == 
      $(document).height()) {
        if(track_load <= total_groups && loading==false){
           loading=true;
            $.post('store/loadmore',{'group_no': track_load}, 
            function(data){
               $("#productContainer").append(data).fadeIn(); 
               track_load++; //loaded group increment
               loading = false;
            });
        }
     }
   });
});
```

PHP

```
$items_per_group = 25;
$get_total_rows = /*count from SQL table*/
$total_groups = ceil($get_total_rows/$items_per_group);

if(isset($_POST)){
      $group_number = filter_var($_POST["group_no"], 
       FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

       if(!is_numeric($group_number)){
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Invalid number!');
        exit();
       }

       $position = ($group_number * $items_per_group);
       /*PHP Query*/
}
```

This solution is working pretty well but has following issues:

1. Products are loaded only when user scrolls to complete end of the page - `But needed thing is that as soon as user reaches last element of current view then next products shall be loaded.`
2. After scrolling complete bottom of page first time and then i user scroll up then also, AJAX call is fired.

How can i prevent these issues and then i will have great solution.

I tried below solution also:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == 
      $(document).height()-`200[height of footer]`) {}
```

**Second solution**

```
var end = $("#copyright").offset().top;<br/>
  var viewEnd = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();<br/>
  var distance = end - viewEnd;<br/>
  if(distance <400{load products ajax}
```

But none of it seems working as expected

Comment: whomsoever downvoted.. please leave a comment. It is no good to downvote without any reason

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic concept of checking if an element is visible within a scrollable container:
http://jsfiddle.net/7fpqcqw1/

```
window.elementInView = false;
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var $window = $(window);

    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    window.elementInView = ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop)) ? true : false;

    return window.elementInView;
}
```

Use the window.elementInView variable whereever you call isScrolledIntoView(elem) with a condition to return true only once and not calling the function anymore.

This function is provided by another user in another stack overflow question: [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

Comment: I have tried this and this works pretty well and solved the issue of loading products while first scroll instead of reaching end of the page. Approach i have followed is to embed a hidden `input` with some ID and margin from top say 300px. Is this right approach???

Comment: Secondly, it still have the issues that if a person refreshes the page or already at bottom of page then if he scroll up then ajax request is fired again and products are loaded. How can i prevent this?

Comment: 1) just try 2) page refresh thing can only be done server side. cache the ajax loaded stuff and set a var, so you can have a condition around the scroll script. 2.1) save the function return value into a window var an set it to true if the function returns true. wrap the function call with a condition of the window var, so its only fired once. All these are just examples.

Comment: Can you just illustrate one example to get bettr understsnding.